Slint: Access the position of repeated elements
I try to write a slint gui that does some custom layouting, until know I have this code (the position computations are more complicated, but the relevant thing is that they depend on the previous elements):
import { Button } from "std-widgets.slint";

export component AppWindow inherits Window {
    b1 := Button {
        text: "B1";
        x: 0;
        y: 0;
    }
    b2 := Button {
        text: "B2";
        x: b1.x + b1.width;
        y: b1.y + b1.height;
    }
    b3 := Button {
        text: "B3";
        x: b2.x + b2.width;
        y: b2.y + b2.height;
    }
}


An this does in principle work as intended, but this allows only to have a compile-time fixed number of elements in the layout, but what I need is a dynamic number of elements.
So something like this (which does not work) is desired:
export component AppWindow inherits Window {
    for x[index] in 5: b := Button {
        text: "B1";
        x: b[index-1].x + b[index-1].width;
        y: b[index-1].y + b[index-1].height;
    }
}

Does anybody know how to access repeated elements in such a way?
